# How do you reference an optional rule `rulename?` from within a grammar action in Antlr4?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

**TL;DR :** How do you reference an optional rule `rulename?` from within a grammar action?

---

I tried this and it obviously failed because *$value* is `None` (null) when the `value` rule is not matched, and accessing an attribute of a null reference gives an error:

```
| NOP3 value? {print( $value.ret )}
```

Then I tried this, but now I get the error that I can't reference the RuleContext *$value* itself but I have to reference one of its attributes: (*error(67): missing attribute access on rule reference value in $value*)

```
| NOP3 value? {print( $value.ret if $value is not None else "empty" )}
```

I was able to make it work with this dirty workaround that injects custom hacky code that plugs to an if whose else clause if triggered when the subrule *value* is not matched, but it's ugly and I guess there should be a better solution for this:

```
    | NOP3 value? {else:
    class obj(object):
        pass    
    localctx._value = obj()
    localctx._value.ret = None
print( $value.ret )}
```

Note: *$value.ret* is the return value of the sub-rule.

**Edit:** An iteration on *Bart Kiers*' answer:
 As I really don't need to do anything if the *value* sub-rule is not matched, I was able to simplify it like this:

```
| NOP3 ( value {do_something()} )?
```

So basically made `value?` a sub-rule and embedded the action inside it, instead of the parent rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must test for `None` is that case:

```
| NOP3 value? {print("nada" if $value is None else $value.ret)}
```

or something like this:

```
| NOP3 v=value? {print("nada" if $v is None else $v.ret)}
```

or even something like this could work:

```
| NOP3 (value {print($value.ret)} | {print("nada")})
```

(assuming you're embedding Python code)

However, I highly recommend *not* embedding target specific code in your grammar: that is better done in a listener or visitor.

Comment: Unfortunately if do that I get `error(67): missing attribute access on rule reference value in $value` as in my second snippet (which is almost the same as your example)

Comment: About using actions, I implemented my compiler almost completely with listeners before realizing that by using grammar actions the code was much simpler for achieving the same results.  In the unlikely event that I want to switch to a different target language, I can translate the minimal snippets of code in the actions.

Comment: Ah, I missed that second snippet. Let me add another suggestion.

Comment: @Petruza checkout my edit with `v=value?`. If that doesn't work, I'll create a small Python demo later tonight and see if I can get something working.

Comment: Thanks, the 3rd option worked great. The second option doesn't as v=value is not different as using value directly, you still need to reference its attributes.

Comment: I had hoped the with second option the `v=` would have been declared in some outer scope so that it would have been available. Apparently not. Good the hear the third one did it.

Comment: Right, I hadn't realized that I could make `value` an inline sub-rule and apply the action only to it, adding the optional `?` to both of them.